# Salesforce GraphQL API implementation on Apex

Tags: graphql, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Just saw salesforce graphQL API. When making a callout from dev console it works fine but as soon as try the same to do it from Apex which is getting called from LWC.

```
String endpoint = ‘/services/data/v52.0/graphql’;
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
request.setMethod(‘POST’);
request.setHeader(‘Authorization’, ‘Bearer ’ + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader(‘Content-Type’, ‘application/json’);
request.setBody(‘{“query”: ” { uiapi { query { Contact { edges { node { Id Name { value } } } } } }} ” }’);
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse response = http.send(request);
System.debug(response.getBody());
```

Anyone who has tried GraphQL in salesforce using wire adapters or by just making http callout from apex?

We tried using LWC GraphQL wire adapters which didn't work
So tried HTTP callout in Apex and called that method from LWC but getting Session ID not valid for Rest API

Answer (score 0):

LWC sessions ids are not valid for API access. You can use callouts (Remote Site Settings, Named Credentials) to any server except "this" salesforce instance. To call APIs of "this" you need to establish a separate session id.

There's a hack with visualforce page (meh) and "pro" way with Auth Provider + Named Credential. See https://sfdcpanther.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/how-to-call-salesforce-api-from-lightning-component/

See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/55306/799 too